# How to set the stacksize with C++11 std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I've been trying to familiarize myself with the **std::thread** library in C++11, and have arrived at a stumbling block.

Initially I come from a posix threads background, and was wondering how does one setup the stack size of the std::thread prior to construction, as I can't seem to find any references to performing such a task.

Using pthreads setting the stack size is done like this:

```
void* foo(void* arg);
.
.
.
.
pthread_attr_t attribute;
pthread_t thread;

pthread_attr_init(&attribute);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attribute,1024);
pthread_create(&thread,&attribute,foo,0);
pthread_join(thread,0);
```

Is there something similar when using **std::thread**?

I've been using the following reference:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: you could get native handler and set stack size? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle

Comment: @billz Once the thread has been created it is too late.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Billy: There are many scenarios where one may want to create many threads for a thread pool and assume that all the data/memory the thread will require will external hence the stack can be set small - essentially enough to house any calls or code nothing else.

Comment: @BillyONeal i'm working on a program that needs a lot worker threads, these threads doesn't need a big stack size (running them at a 500 kb stack/worker thread), the std::thread default stack size is 8 megabytes/thread. if i want 10 worker threads, that's either 80 megabytes of ram using std::thread, or 5 megabytes of ram using pthreads..

Comment: @hanshenrik: Not really. 8MB (on Linux) and 1MB (on Windows) is the default stack size *reservation* -- it'll only generally consume physical RAM if pages are touched.

Comment: @BillyONeal so you're saying a thread that doesn't do anything, just `void threadEntry(){for(;;){this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));}}` but have a stack size of 0.5MB use just as much memory as a thread doing the same with a 8MB stack size?

Comment: @BillyONeal damn, seems you're right, i wrote some [code](https://gist.github.com/divinity76/38ab577e546c9828cd58ea2544c87801) to test it, then installed a debian 9 amd64 minimal with kernel 4.9.110 , g++ 6.3.0, and 152 MB ram and 0 swap (which seems to be nearly the minimum debian will boot on without tweaking the `initial ramdisk` - somewhere between 140 and 152MB ram) on VMWare, and both mode 1 (std::thread with 8MB stack) and mode 2 (pthread with 512 kb stack) are able to run *exactly* 700 threads before failing! cool  - during boot it needs ~152 MB but after boot its 65MB ram, unfortunate

Answer (score 28):

> Initially I come from a posix threads background, and was wondering how does one setup the stack size of the std::thread prior to construction, as I can't seem to find any references to performing such a task.

You can't. `std::thread` doesn't support this because `std::thread` is standardized, and C++ does not require that a machine even has a stack, much less a fixed-size one.

pthreads are more restrictive in terms of the hardware that they support, and it assumes that there is some fixed stack size per thread. (So you can configure this)

Comment: +1 but that is a very disappointing and short-sighted result. I'd have expected a trait or stack allocator trait mechanism at the very least.

Comment: @ZamfirKerlukson: The language designers did think about this. You get the native handle from the Thread object. Then manipulate it with appropriate native function calls for your platform. But the reason they made it hard is that doing it is usually a mistake and when actually required is very/very rare.

Comment: I don't see how to change the stack size using the native handle. Any hints? Moreover, the Mac OSX default for a pthread stack size is 512kB. This is quite small.

Comment: As far as I am aware you can't change the stack size for a thread after it has started.

Comment: I like so generic software that it has 0 flexibility. I wonder if there exists an implementation that has no stack?

Answer (score 19):

As Loki Astari already said, it is extremely rare to actually need a non-default stack-size and usually either a mistake or the result of bad coding.

- If you feel like the default stack size is too big for your needs and want to reduce it, just forget about it. Every modern OS now uses virtual memory / on-demand commit, which means that memory is only reserved, not actually allocated, until you access the pages. Reducing the stack size will **not** reduce your actual memory footprint.
- Due to this very behaviour, OSes can afford to set the default stack size to very big values. E.g. on a vanilla Debian this is 8MB (`ulimit -s`) which should be enough for every need. If you still manage to hit that limit, my first idea would be that your code is wrong, so you should first and foremost review it and move things to the heap, transform recursive functions into loops, etc.
- If despite all of this you *really really* need to change the stack size (i.e. increase it, since reducing it is useless), on POSIX you can always use [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) at the start of your program to increase the default stack size. Sure this will affect all threads, but only the ones who need it will actually use the additional memory.
- Last but not least, in all fairness I can see a corner case where reducing the stack size would make sense: if you have tons of threads on a 32 bits system, they could eat up your virtual address space (again, not the actual memory consumption) up to the point that you don't have enough address space available for the heap. Again, [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) is your friend here even though I'd advise to move to a 64 bits system to benefit from the larger virtual address space (and if your program is that big anyway, you'll probably benefit from the additional RAM too).

Comment: I tried `setrlimit` on Linux and Cygwin. On Cygwin, it always fails. On Linux, it only changes the size of the main thread. The `ulimit -s` solution works on Linux. On OSX, it only affects the size of the main thread. The Mac OS X default for a pthread stack size is 512kB. This is quite small. It is a pity we can't change the default stack size using `std::thread`.

Comment: 640 kb used to be enough for everybody

Comment: ", it is extremely rare to actually need a non-default stack-size".  Speak for yourself.  I work with large matrix operations and often the default stack size is not enough.

Comment: On microcontrollers you most likely want to be able to set the stack size. Just another agument to support the preconception that C++ is not good for microcontrollers. Sad.

Comment: @Sebastian I agree that being able to control stack sizes on a microcontroller would be helpful, but I feel it's more common to be using an RTOS in those environments in which case you'd be using that RTOS's API for thread manipulation.  C++ is still viable there, albeit with some features being less useful.

Comment: Windows has a 1MB default stack. Clang has to increase the stack size to have enough space to instantiate recursive templates. Are they writing bad code?

Answer (score 18):

I have also been investigating this issue. For some applications, the default stack size is not adequate. Examples: the program does deep recursion dependent on the specific problem it is solving; the program needs to create many threads and memory consumption is an issue.

Here is a summary of (partial) solutions / workarounds I found:

- g++ supports a `-fsplit-stack` option on Linux. [See](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks) for more information about Split stacks. Here is summary from their website:

> The goal of split stacks is to permit a discontiguous stack which is
>   grown automatically as needed. This means that you can run multiple
>   threads, each starting with a small stack, and have the stack grow and
>   shrink as required by the program.

Remark: `-fsplit-stack` only worked for me after I started using the [gold linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29). 
It seems clang++ will also support this flag. The version I tried (clang++ 3.3) crashed when trying to compile my application using the flag `-fsplit-stack`.

- On Linux, set the stack size by executing `ulimit -s <size>` before starting your application. `size` is the stack size in Kbs. Remark: the command `unlimit -s unlimited` did not affect the size of threads created with `std::thread`. When I used `ulimit -s unlimited`, the main thread could grow, but the threads created with `std::thread` had the default size.
- On Windows using Visual Studio, we can use use the linker `/STACK` parameter or `/STACKSIZE` in the module definition file, this is the default size for all created threads. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8cxs58a6%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) for more information. We can also modify this parameter in any executable using the command line tool [EDITBIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xd3shwhf.aspx).
- On Windows using mingw g++, we can use the option `-Wl,--stack,<size>`. For some reason, when using cygwin g++, this flag only affects the size of the main thread.

Approaches that **did** not work for me:

- `ulimit -s <size>` on OSX. It affects only the size of the main thread. Moreover, the Mac OSX default for a pthread stack size is 512kB.
- [`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) only affects the size of the main thread on Linux and OSX. On cygwin, it never worked for me, it seems it always returns an error.

For OSX, the only alternative seems to use `boost::thread` instead of `std::thread`, but this is not nice if we want to stick with the standard. I hope g++ and clang++ will also support `-fsplit-stack` on OSX in the future.

Answer (score 16):

I found this in Scott Meyers book `Overview of the New C++(C++0x)`, as it's quite long I can't post it as a comment, is this helpful?

> There is also a standard API for getting at the platform-specific
>   handles behind threads, mutexes, condition variables, etc.. These
>   handles are assumed to be the mechanism for setting thread priorities,
>   setting stack sizes, etc. (Regarding setting stack sizes, Anthony
>   Williams notes: "Of those OSs that support setting the stack size,
>   they all do it differently. If you're coding for a specify platform
>   (such that use of the native_handle would be OK), then you could use
>   that platform's facilities to switch stacks. e.g. on POSIX you could
>   use makecontext and swapcontext along with explicit allocation of a
>   stack, and on Windows you could use Fibers. You could then use the
>   platform-specific facilities (e.g. Linker flags) to set the default
>   stack size to something really tiny, and then switch stacks to
>   something bigger where necessary.“)

Comment: +1 Thats an interesting albeit round about way of setting the stacksize.

Comment: Doesn't help you if you want to configure it before the thread starts.

Answer (score 15):

Was looking for the answer to this myself just now.

It appears that while std::thread does not support this, boost::thread does.

In particular, you can use [boost::thread::attributes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.attributes) to accomplish this:

```
boost::thread::attributes attrs;
attrs.set_stack_size(4096*10);
boost::thread myThread(attrs, fooFunction, 42);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do some modifications like this if you don't want to include a big library.

It is still dependend C++ compiler STL library. (Clang / MSVC now)

[HackingSTL Library](https://github.com/metarutaiga/HackingSTL/blob/master/thread)

```
std::thread thread = std::stacking_thread(65536, []{
    printf("Hello, world!\n"); 
});
```

Comment: Nice hack, thanks ! Recent post/answers often are more appropriate than the most voted. Former answers are getting old.