# How can I override thread creation behavior in C++11?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11

In Apple's implementation of the pthread lib, the only way to change a thread's stack size is by passing a parameter to pthread_create (changing RLIMIT_STACK only works in Linux).

Is there a way to change C++11's thread creation behavior? Can I overide a function somehow?

I would like to use C++11 async with stack sizes much larger than 512K. Possible?

Comment: maybe this will help <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871763/how-to-set-the-stacksize-with-c11-stdthread>

Comment: I'd consider redesigning some of your code to not use so much stack... Yes, I know, it's not the answer you were looking for...

Comment: It's for programming competitions. Sometimes you need a big stack.