# How to specify stack size when create thread using Threadpool in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a C++ project in which I'm trying to create hundreds of threads using the below class. If there is a few threads, everything works fine. But if I try to create 1000 threads, only around 500 (not more than 600) threads can be created. In this situation, I would like to change the default stack size of each thread.

So, how can I change the stack size?

```
class CThreadPool
{
    static const int MAX_THREADS = 10000;

public:

    template <typename T>
    static void QueueUserWorkItem(void (T::*function)(void),
        T *object, ULONG flags = WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION)
    {
        typedef std::pair<void (T::*)(), T *> CallbackType;
        std::auto_ptr<CallbackType> p(new CallbackType(function, object));
        WT_SET_MAX_THREADPOOL_THREADS(flags, MAX_THREADS);

        if (::QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc<T>, p.get(), flags))
        {
            // The ThreadProc now has the responsibility of deleting the pair.
            p.release();
        }
        else
        {
            throw GetLastError();
        }
    }

private:

    template <typename T>
    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(PVOID context)
    {
        typedef std::pair<void (T::*)(), T *> CallbackType;

        std::auto_ptr<CallbackType> p(static_cast<CallbackType *>(context));

        (p->second->*p->first)();
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you need so many threads? The point of using a thread pool is to reduce the number of threads used

Comment: Try BOOL SetThreadStackGuarantee(  PULONG StackSizeInBytes );

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` I thought this heresy had been purged from the standard a long time ago

Comment: @las [SetThreadStackGuarantee](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadstackguarantee) *"Sets the minimum size of the stack \[...\] that will be **available during any stack overflow exceptions**."* This is useful for handling stack overflow exceptions only. The call can only be made, once a thread has been created. At that point, there's no way to change the default stack size allotted to the thread.

Comment: I would reconsider the design of your program. It's hard to see how so many threads could be useful.

Comment: You can't with standard threads. Maybe this will help. [How to set the stacksize with C++11 std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871763/how-to-set-the-stacksize-with-c11-stdthread)

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, correct. My bad, Well, then the only option that remains is to use the native thread API and set dwStackSize upon thread creation: [CreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread)

Answer (score 2):

[`QueueUserWorkItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoollegacyapiset/nf-threadpoollegacyapiset-queueuserworkitem) is a legacy API.  It offers no way to set the stack size of the threads in its pool.

`QueueUserWorkItem()` was deprecated in Windows Vista, replaced by a [new Thread Pool API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-pool-api) that offers much more control.  The direct replacement of `QueueUserWorkItem()` in this API is [`SubmitThreadpoolWork()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-submitthreadpoolwork).  Its work items are created with [`CreateThreadpoolWork()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-createthreadpoolwork), which allows an optional user-supplied `TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON` struct to be passed to it to control the environment that the work item runs in.

You can create a new thread pool using [`CreateThreadpool()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-createthreadpool), then set the stack size for this pool's  threads using [`SetThreadpoolStackInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-setthreadpoolstackinformation), then create a `TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON` and associate it with this pool using [`SetThreadpoolCallbackPool()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadpoolcallbackpool), and then finally pass that `TP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON` to `CreateThreadpoolWork()`.

Comment: Thanks. In current stage I am not considering to change the thread management in the project. But I will definitely consider your suggestion if so.