# std::thread helper class to add thread name and stack size

Tags: c++, stdthread

I would like to make a helper class (or subclass of std::thread) to allow stack size to be set and also thread name.
If the thread is running on a platform, which does not support e.g. stack size, the number should just be ignored.

I was thinking of a "ThreadHelper", which has the extended constructor interface, and just returns a std::thread.

To be honest, I have very little experience when it comes to all the template stuff, which std::thread contains.

Right now the thread class is instantiated like:
m_thread = new std::thread(&Button::Process, this);
I would like something like:
m_thread = new ThreadHelper.Create(&Button::Process, this, stackSize, name);

Any advices are appreciated.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: About stack size: [bad luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871763/how-to-set-the-stacksize-with-c11-stdthread). You'll rely on OS-specific API for that. For the name, there are quite a number of alternatives, such the process function/functor accepting another name parameter. This can be handled with standard `std::thread` without extension class.

Comment: I would avoid creating your `std::thread` dynamically unless you really have to (unlikely).  `std::thread m_thread = std::thread(&Button::Process, this);` // should be fine

Comment: Just use boost thread, write and maintain such kind of low level cross platform code is painful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you could do:
You need a wrapper around your thread start function so that you can call the appropriate functions before (and possibly after) your thread function is running. It might also be a good idea to include a try-catch block and do some error processing.

```
template <typename ThreadStartFnc>
struct ThreadWrapper
{
   ThreadStartFnc fnc;
   const char *name;     // (1) Note: careful, just a pointer here, not a string. See below.
   size_t priority;
   size_t stack_size;

   ThreadWrapper(...) // constructor here...

   void operator()()
   {
      SetThreadName(name);         // Whatever that is on your system
      SetThreadPriority(priority); // dito
      SetStackSize(stack_size);    // not all systems allow this
      try {
         fnc();
      }
      catch(...) {
         cerr << "Exception caught"; // Do exception processing here.
      }
   }
};
```

And you need a simple way to instantiate an std::thread with the wrapper "inserted", like this:

```
template <typename Fnc>
std::thread make_thread(const Fnc& f, const char *name, size_t priority=0, size_t stack_size=0)
{
   return std::thread(ThreadWrapper<Fnc>(f, name, priority, stack_size));
}
```

And that is basically it. std::thread accepts a Functor object, which is what ThreadWrapper is. It calls Functor() to start the thread, which is `void operator()()`. This function uses the additional parameters name, priority, stack_size to set everything up and then call your function.

Enhance this with the C++11/14/17 goodies like variadic template parameters and/or lambda functions as you like.

Below is the actual wrapper function that we use (although we do not use a Functor, we use boost::bind and a static template function instead).

```
    template <typename Fnc>
    static inline void run_cstr(const Fnc &f, const char *name, DWORD priority)
    {
        int rc=_configthreadlocale(0);
/*
        _configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE);
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
*/
        SetThreadName(name);
        watchdog::set_thread_info(name);
        ::SetThreadPriority(::GetCurrentThread(), priority);
        _set_se_translator(&_se_translator);
        _set_invalid_parameter_handler(&my_invalid_parameter_handler);
        __try {
            f();
        }
        __except (global_seh_handler(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation()) ) {
        }
    }
```

It sets the ThreadName for Visual Studio (SetThreadName), sets the locale, sets the thread priority, connects our software watchdog to the thread and also sets up a global Windows try/catch handler for all exceptions including access violations etc....
The `global_seh_handler` will be executed if any uncaught exceptions (including invalid std lib parameters) end up here. It will write a crash dump file which we use for post mortem debugging.

(1) Note: I've used a `const char *name` for the thread name, because I am assuming that the thread will run immediately, while the string for the thread name is still available. That is actually unsafe, if you are storing objects of type ThreadWrapper for a longer period. You'd need to change `const char*` to `std::string` then.

Comment: P.S. google THREADNAME_INFO for how to set the thread name in Windows/Visual Studio

Comment: It is a great help for me. I am not able to compile a reduced example:
`template <typename ThreadStartFnc>
struct ThreadWrapper
{
  ThreadStartFnc fnc;

  ThreadWrapper(ThreadStartFnc _fnc)
  {
    fnc = _fnc;
  }
  void operator()()
  {
    fnc();
  }
};

template <typename Fnc>
std::thread make_thread(const Fnc& f)
{
return std::thread(ThreadWrapper<Fnc>(f));
}

void TestThread() {}

int main()
{
  std::thread t = make_thread(TestThread);
}
`
I get an error:  'ThreadWrapper<ThreadStartFnc>::fnc': a member of a class template cannot acquire a function type

Comment: That's because void TestThread(){} is not a Functor. It has no operator(), implicitly or explicitly. But don't change TestThread just now. My guess is

```
std::thread t = make_thread(&TestThread);
```

will work, since Fnc will be of void(*)() then. IOW, a pointer to a static function. And that pointer _can_ be called with fnc();

A Functor is anything for which the expression  `fnc()` is valid. IOW, anything that can be called.

Problem is, there is no type that can accept a value of "TestThread". Only "TestThread*" so to speak. So your problem is with the parameter of make_thread

Comment: Using a pointer worked. Thanks!
It has been such a great help.
Now I will try to implement the required functionality for setting the stack size (runs on FreeRTOS embedded OS).